# Real-world CQI-to-MCS and SNR-to-CQI tables?

Tags: wireless, modulation, bit-rate, channel-coding

How can I get real-world CQI-to-MCS and SNR-to-CQI tables? I am particularly looking for 5G-NR or LTE-A related tables.

Can someone share any references?

Edit: I had found one table for CQI-MCS conversion [here](https://www.sharetechnote.com/html/Handbook_LTE_CQI.html#Two_Important_CQI_Table). But there are no details as to how this table is drawn (See the image below). Furthermore, it uses 20 Resource Blocks (RBs), where as I am particularly looking table for a 100-RBs transmission system. However, a table for any configuration can work for at least the proof-of-concept of my simulation, if not 100-RB data.

[image: CQI-to-MCS table]

Comment: As I commented on your cross post. What have you found so far so we don’t duplicate effort and waste it.

Comment: Right, Thanks. I have made edits to the question.